# w2ui configuration of the Grid using the JSON along with the records data

Tags: jquery, html, w2ui

is there a way of using the JSON to configure the column configuration on the Grid along with the records?

http://w2ui.com/web/home

Answer (score 1):

There is no default grid property that accepts JSON, but you can certainly construct the grid columns and records yourself using your own JSON payload (i.e., coming back from web service). I just finished doing this for my client.

javascript function:

```
  function constructGrid(db) {
console.log("Constructing the grid...");

var dynamicColumns = [];
var dynamicSearches = [];
var tableData = [];

/* Get the columns of the table */
var columns = db.Payload.Metadata.Columns;

/* Assign column and search properties */
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  var search = {
    field: columns[i].Name,
    caption: columns[i].Name.split('_').join(' ')
  };

  var col = {
    sortable: true,
    searchable: true,
    resizable: true,
    field: columns[i].Name,
    caption: columns[i].Name.split('_').join(' ')
  };

  /* assign column length */
  var colLength = col.caption.length;
  if (columns[i].DataLength > colLength) {
    colLength = columns[i].DataLength;
    if (colLength > 999) {
      colLength = colLength / 70;
    }
  }
  var colSize = colLength * 10;
  col["size"] = colSize + 'px';

  if (columns[i].DataType == "NUMBER") {
    if (columns[i].DataScale > 0) {
      col['editable'] = { type: 'float' };
      search['type'] = 'float';
    } else {
      col['editable'] = { type: 'int' };
      search['type'] = 'int';
    }

    col['render'] = function(record, index, col_index) {
      var html = null;          
      var value = this.getCellValue(index, col_index);         

      if (value !== undefined) {
        var t = typeof value;
        if (t == "number") {
          if (!isNaN(value)) {
            html = this.getCellValue(index, col_index);               
          }
        }
      };

      return html;
    };

  } else if (columns[i].DataType == "DATE" ){
    col['editable'] = { type: 'date' };
    col['render'] = "date:mm/dd/yyyy";
    search['type'] = 'date';
  } else {
    col['editable'] = { type: 'text' };
    search['type'] = 'text';
  }

  /* Alter grid header to visually indicate required field */
  col['caption'] = createColumnCaption(columns[i]);

  /* If foreign key table, we need to build dropdown */
  if (columns[i].FKColumn != null && columns[i].FKTableCount <= maxDropdownItems) {        
    col['editable'] = { type: 'select', showAll: true };
    col['editable'].items = [{id: '', text: ''}].concat(dddws[i]);
    col['render'] = function(record, index, column_index) {
      var html = '';          
      var map = dddwsMap[column_index];          
      var value = this.getCellValue(index, column_index);

      if (value !== undefined && map !== undefined) {
        var t = typeof value;
        if (t == "number") {
          if (!isNaN(value)) {
            html = map[this.getCellValue(index, column_index)];               
          }
        } else {
          html = map[this.getCellValue(index, column_index)];            
        }
      };

      return html;
    };
  }

  /* set background color of cell for primary key */
  if (columns[i].IsPrimaryKey == true) {
    col['style'] = "background-color: HSL(0, 0%, 51%); background-clip: padding-box;";
  }

  /* Any audit column is defaulted to hidden. User can display them and search for them if they want */
  if (columns[i].IsAuditable == true) {
    col['hidden'] = true;
  }

  /* Add both search and column to their grid property arrays */
  dynamicColumns.push(col);
  dynamicSearches.push(search);
}

w2ui['grid'].columns = dynamicColumns;
w2ui['grid'].searches = dynamicSearches;
w2ui['grid'].multiSearch = true;
w2ui['grid'].multiSort = true;

console.log("Dynamic Grid columns:");
console.log(dynamicColumns);
console.log("Dynamic Search columns:");
console.log(dynamicSearches);

/* clear table data */
tableData.length = 0;

/* Load table data only once */
if (tableData.length == 0) {
  db.Payload.Records.forEach(function (rec, index, array) {
    var row = {};

    row['recid'] = index;
    row['editable'] = true;
    row['rowIndicator'] = "R";
    row['Code'] = rec.Code;
    row['OptimisticValue'] = rec.OptimisticValue;

    /* Construct the columns of a row */
    db.Payload.Metadata.Columns.forEach(function (col, i, a) {          
      if (columns[i].DataType == "NUMBER") {
        if (!isNaN(rec.ColumnData[i])) {
          row[col.Name] = parseInt(rec.ColumnData[i]);              
        }
      } else {
        row[col.Name] = rec.ColumnData[i];
      }
    });

    /* Add the row of columns to the table */
    tableData.push(row);
  });
}

w2ui['grid'].records = tableData;
```

}

JSON object used by function:

```
 {
  "ID": 0,
  "Payload": {
    "Table": "AMTB_AIR_INJECTION_TYPE",
    "Metadata": {
      "Table": "AMTB_AIR_INJECTION_TYPE",
      "ContainsMappingColumn": false,
      "Columns": [
        {
          "Name": "AIR_INJECTION_TYPE_CODE",
          "DataType": "CHAR",
          "DataScale": 0,
          "DataLength": 2,
          "ForeignKeyTable": null,
          "FKParentTable": null,
          "FKPosition": 1,
          "FKColumn": null,
          "FKTableCount": 0,
          "IsFKMapping": false,
          "IsPrimaryKey": true,
          "IsOptimistic": false,
          "IsRequired": true,
          "IsAutoGenerated": false,
          "IsAuditable": false,
          "CanValidateAgainstFKTable": false
        },
        {
          "Name": "AIR_INJECTION_TYPE_DESC",
          "DataType": "VARCHAR2",
          "DataScale": 0,
          "DataLength": 30,
          "ForeignKeyTable": null,
          "FKParentTable": null,
          "FKPosition": 1,
          "FKColumn": null,
          "FKTableCount": 0,
          "IsFKMapping": false,
          "IsPrimaryKey": false,
          "IsOptimistic": false,
          "IsRequired": true,
          "IsAutoGenerated": false,
          "IsAuditable": false,
          "CanValidateAgainstFKTable": false
        },
        {
          "Name": "INACTIVE_FLAG",
          "DataType": "CHAR",
          "DataScale": 0,
          "DataLength": 1,
          "ForeignKeyTable": null,
          "FKParentTable": null,
          "FKPosition": 1,
          "FKColumn": null,
          "FKTableCount": 0,
          "IsFKMapping": false,
          "IsPrimaryKey": false,
          "IsOptimistic": false,
          "IsRequired": true,
          "IsAutoGenerated": false,
          "IsAuditable": false,
          "CanValidateAgainstFKTable": false
        },
        {
          "Name": "USER_ID_LAST_UPDT",
          "DataType": "VARCHAR2",
          "DataScale": 0,
          "DataLength": 50,
          "ForeignKeyTable": null,
          "FKParentTable": null,
          "FKPosition": 1,
          "FKColumn": null,
          "FKTableCount": 0,
          "IsFKMapping": false,
          "IsPrimaryKey": false,
          "IsOptimistic": false,
          "IsRequired": true,
          "IsAutoGenerated": false,
          "IsAuditable": true,
          "CanValidateAgainstFKTable": false
        },
        {
          "Name": "TMSP_LAST_UPDT",
          "DataType": "DATE",
          "DataScale": 0,
          "DataLength": 23,
          "ForeignKeyTable": null,
          "FKParentTable": null,
          "FKPosition": 1,
          "FKColumn": null,
          "FKTableCount": 0,
          "IsFKMapping": false,
          "IsPrimaryKey": false,
          "IsOptimistic": true,
          "IsRequired": true,
          "IsAutoGenerated": false,
          "IsAuditable": true,
          "CanValidateAgainstFKTable": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "Records": [
      {
        "Code": "AS",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Air Sparging",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/23/2019 04:11:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "AS",
          "Air Sparging",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/23/2019 4:11:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "BV",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Bioventing",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/22/2019 20:49:02",
        "ColumnData": [
          "BV",
          "Bioventing",
          "N",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/22/2019 20:49:2.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "OI",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Oxygen Injection",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/22/2019 20:49:02",
        "ColumnData": [
          "OI",
          "Oxygen Injection",
          "N",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/22/2019 20:49:2.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "AA",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "AA Description",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "03/01/2019 11:34:48",
        "ColumnData": [
          "AA",
          "AA Description",
          "N",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "3/1/2019 11:34:48.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "BB",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "BB Description",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "03/01/2019 11:34:48",
        "ColumnData": [
          "BB",
          "BB Description",
          "N",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "3/1/2019 11:34:48.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "TE",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Description 1",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "03/01/2019 12:40:59",
        "ColumnData": [
          "TE",
          "Description 1",
          "N",
          "omar.elboury@cgi.com",
          "3/1/2019 12:40:59.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "z4",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/23/2019 05:52:45",
        "ColumnData": [
          "z4",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/23/2019 5:52:45.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "z6",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/23/2019 05:58:57",
        "ColumnData": [
          "z6",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/23/2019 5:58:57.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "z7",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZz",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/23/2019 06:54:30",
        "ColumnData": [
          "z7",
          "Test ZZz",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/23/2019 6:54:30.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "A1",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 08:34:16",
        "ColumnData": [
          "A1",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 8:34:16.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "P9",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZI",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/29/2019 09:43:07",
        "ColumnData": [
          "P9",
          "Test ZZI",
          "Y",
          "omar.elboury@cgi.com",
          "4/29/2019 9:43:7.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "z5",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/23/2019 05:56:36",
        "ColumnData": [
          "z5",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/23/2019 5:56:36.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "QQ",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Scott Test Code",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/05/2019 08:52:37",
        "ColumnData": [
          "QQ",
          "Scott Test Code",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/5/2019 8:52:37.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "z3",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/22/2019 20:55:37",
        "ColumnData": [
          "z3",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/22/2019 20:55:37.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "ZZ",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/25/2019 06:24:32",
        "ColumnData": [
          "ZZ",
          "Test ZZ",
          "N",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/25/2019 6:24:32.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Z2",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/22/2019 20:54:03",
        "ColumnData": [
          "Z2",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/22/2019 20:54:3.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Z9",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/26/2019 06:56:40",
        "ColumnData": [
          "Z9",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/26/2019 6:56:40.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q1",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q1",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q2",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q2",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q3",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZz",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q3",
          "Test ZZz",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q4",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q4",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q5",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q5",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q6",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Scott Test Code",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q6",
          "Scott Test Code",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q7",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q7",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q8",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q8",
          "Test ZZ",
          "N",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "q9",
        "OriginalCode": null,
        "Description": "Test ZZ",
        "RowIndicator": "R",
        "IsInactive": false,
        "OptimisticValue": "04/27/2019 19:08:49",
        "ColumnData": [
          "q9",
          "Test ZZ",
          "Y",
          "stephen.bowers@cgi.com",
          "4/27/2019 19:8:49.0"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "ResponseMessages": [],
  "ResponseStatusCode": 1,
  "ResponseMessage": ""
}
```

Comment: May be a simple example would help

Comment: I added the javascript function that constructs the grid columns and records and provided an example of the JSON payload this structure uses.